# Cannot play sound with win32 XAudio2 in window procedure callback

Tags: winapi, xaudio2

I'm preparing a birthday present for my classmate and I want to play the birthday song with `XAudio2`. However, I couldn't hear any sound. The code that plays sound was failed in window procedure, but succeed in `main` or `WinMain`.

The code below is from MSDN. It is called when `WndProc` got `WM_PAINT` message.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
LPCWSTR strFileName = L".\\bgm.wav";
// Open the file
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
    strFileName,
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

DWORD dwChunkSize;
DWORD dwChunkPosition;
FindChunk(hFile, fourccRIFF, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
DWORD filetype;
ReadChunkData(hFile, &filetype, sizeof(DWORD), dwChunkPosition);
if (filetype != fourccWAVE) return S_FALSE;
FindChunk(hFile, fourccFMT, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
ReadChunkData(hFile, &(wfx), dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
FindChunk(hFile, fourccDATA, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
BYTE* pDataBuffer = new BYTE[dwChunkSize];
ReadChunkData(hFile, pDataBuffer, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
buf.AudioBytes = dwChunkSize;
buf.pAudioData = pDataBuffer;
buf.Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM;
hr = pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice(&(pSourceVoice), (WAVEFORMATEX*)&(wfx));
if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;  // My code returns here with XAUDIO_E_INVALID_CALL
if (FAILED(hr = pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&buf)))
    return hr;
pSourceVoice->Start();
return hr;
```

And what's more, where can I put the code if `pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice` cannot be called in callback?

Comment: Presumably, you're simply receiving several `WM_PAINT` messages, and a subsequent call then fails. The code doesn't protect against re-initiating a playback requests, and ultimately just fails. Put the code into a place that's only called once, or guard it against getting repeatedly called.

Comment: Do you mean that I should guard `hr = pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice(&(pSourceVoice), (WAVEFORMATEX*)&(wfx))`? There's no voice if I change like this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [IXAudio2::CreateSourceVoice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/xaudio2/nf-xaudio2-ixaudio2-createsourcevoice#remarks),

> It is invalid to call CreateSourceVoice from within a **callback**
> (that is, IXAudio2EngineCallback or IXAudio2VoiceCallback). If you
> call CreateSourceVoice within a callback, it returns
> **XAUDIO2_E_INVALID_CALL**.

Comment: According to MSDN, I can't call `CreateSourceVoice` within a callback. Does the "callback" **you said** contain the normal callback function (e.g. `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc`, `CreateSourceVoice` was also called here)?

Comment: @Sam-zhuang Your condition indicates the callback includes the normal callback function.